# E138: Can't write viminfo file $HOME/.viminfo! root $HOME not set in vim

Tags: viminfo, linux-debian

When I :q vim on my debian root account (not even writing), it always displays an error message:

> E138: Can't write viminfo file $HOME/.viminfo!

`.viminfo` didn't exist, so I created it and checked the permissions of `/root` and the file, but they were fine:

```
drwx------  3 root root 4.0K Sep 16 11:13 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 16 11:13 /root/.viminfo
```

`$HOME` exists as an environment variable:

```
~ # echo $HOME
/root
```

in vim `:!echo $HOME` returns empty output. How can I get rid off this error, why isn't vim accepting $HOME?

Comment: Try run vim like this: `env HOME="/root" vim --noplugin`.

Comment: It works, the error is gone but what's the reason that it ignores $HOME? $PATH is accessible in vim for some reason.

Comment: Now try with `vim --noplugin`. Then `env HOME="/root" vim`.

Comment: I see what you did there, works without plugins. So I removed my `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` global config but still get same error. Okay, it's a probably not a vim issue, right?

Comment: Do you have same issue when you run vim as non-root? If this is only happen with root user, then it is very likely the issue is coming from `/root/.vim` directory rather than under `/etc` or `/usr/share/vim`. Try `grep -r HOME /root/.vim /root/.vimrc` .

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. Yes, it is a root only problem. There is no `.vim` directory and I tried to `set HOME=/root/` in my `.vimrc` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Ha ha. Its ok. You need to use: `let $HOME="/root"` .

Comment: Other option is to specify location of viminfo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286866/how-to-tell-vim-to-store-the-viminfo-file-somewhere-else . In your case you will need to replace the `~` with `/root` .

Comment: They both don't work, I guess this is some kind of bug but I found the solution. I'll post it as an answer. Thanks for your support and patience, good sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is some kind of weird bug in the vim stable release, since I installed vim from testing and it just works without further ado.

Answer (score 1):

Logging in and out of the shell solved it for me after all else failed.

Defining `let $HOME="/root"` in `.vimrc` does not help as it can not find `$HOME` directory to read the `.vimrc` if `:!echo $HOME` shows nothing, i.e. is empty. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me

just press enter when this message appears, and reopen the file like `sudo vi file.sh`
and it's done, you can modify and quit the file as you want

just matter of permission issue to `viminfo` file

Comment: If the problem comes from the permissions of the file, using `chmod` and/or `chown` might be a cleaner option than using vim with sudo rights.

Comment: `sudoedit` is generally a better solution than `sudo vi`